# How to use bootstrap-icons with Rails 7 and importmaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

New territory here: Rails 7.0.1, Ruby 3.1.0

`rails new rails7app`

`bin/importmap pin bootstrap` adds bootstrap to the app.

Bootstrap is a combination of js and css. `bootstrap-icons` seems to be basically css. With yarn/npm approach, `yarn install bootstrap-icons` works, but with Rails 7 and no npm `bin/importmap pin bootstrap-icons` does not work. Somewhat expected since this is css.

How do I add `bootstrap-icons` to a basic Rails 7 app?

Answer (score 8):

Importmaps handles javascript only.

You will need to add bootstrap to your gem file

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.3'
```

It is recommended to uncomment the sassc-rails line in the gem file as well

```
gem 'sassc-rails'
```

Then you should be able to add a bootstrap import in your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

EDIT:

Apologies, in order to add the bootstrap-icon portion, your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` needs to import the bootstrap-icon css as well. You can either reference the CDN at import or put the css in your `/vendor` folder and reference the relative path at import.

This is the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` using the CDN method

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
```

Then you can add icons to your view pages.

This code is on my `home.html.erb` and renders a blue alarmclock.

```
<i class="bi-alarm" style="font-size: 2rem; color: cornflowerblue;"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I unpin bootstrap? Is this redundant?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question of how to install bootstrap-icons. Apparently needs to be a node-module. There is a gem 'bootstrap-icons-helper' but it seems to be looking for the node-module. Also seems that Bootstrap maybe moving towards using fonts and not icons.

Comment: apologies, I added additional steps to import the necessary css for icons.

Comment: Thank you. I seem to have icons and fonts mixed up. Here's my code <%= icon("bootstrap", class: "text-success") %> I need to decipher the error. Your code doesn't error, but no clock. I need to dig a bit more.

Comment: Anyone getting garbled UTF-8 instead of the icons?   **Answer**: javascript must be turned on.  I wonder if this is because of using importmaps?

Answer (score 1):

See Joe Thor's first comment and this adds a workaround for something wrong in my set up. What is working for me is adding:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">`

to `application.html.erb` and using the syntax suggested: `<i class="bi bi-bootstrap text-success"></i>`.

The syntax `<%= icon("bootstrap", class: "text-success") %>` looks in `node-modules/…` which aren't installed, so get an error. This is the syntax I had been using. More Railsy.

`@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css");` in `application.scss` is not working for some reason, although it seems it should.

Boostrap seems to be not helping by mixing svg icons and fonts to get "icons".

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this myself until I realized that bootstrap-icons.css references two font files at the top of the file. I found an excellent resource here: https://world.hey.com/aesmail/custom-fonts-in-production-in-rails-7-0-d3765485

First I downloaded the font files from https://github.com/twbs/icons. Be sure you get the actual woff and woff2 files, not the html, when downloading.

I put these two files in app/assets/fonts.

In bootstrap-icons.css I used the font-url helper and changed the file src to:

```
src: font-url("bootstrap-icons.woff2") format("woff2"),
font-url("bootstrap-icons.woff") format("woff");
```

I then changed the file extension to bootstrap-icons.scss

I also added this line to the top of app/assets/config/manifest.js

```
//= link_tree ../fonts
```

In my view I include HAML like this:

```
%i.bi.bi-trash
```

Last I ran

```
rails assets:precompile
```

Works for me in development and production. I didn't have to pin anything or include a node-module.

Comment: hmm not sure about having to run assets:precompile in dev though